# Views display product attributes with prices

Tags: views, commerce

[image: just-eat menu]

How do I create something like this with Views ?
This is my version in the making: 
[image]

this is my view set-up: [image: view set-up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your fields by the title. Specifically:

[image: Basic Views Settings]

click on the settings button of the table format in your view and then select to group by the field that is the same in the 2 entries:

[image: Table Settings]

EDIT:

You can now hide your title field since it will appear in the group name:

[image: Exclude field from display]

and your final view (that you can theme according to your needs) will look like this:

[image: Final View]

Comment: Thanks for the visual aid. But that only groups the products, what I actually need is a product with 2 attributes and the price shown OR 2 products with the same name but with a different attribute and a DISTINCT action on the display name (I tried adapting the Query settings and the aggregation but it doesn't work correctly).

Comment: Allright, thanks :)! How could I only keep the first title?

Comment: Posted my set-up under the other pics, format is table, fields are referenced commerce product fields.

Comment: Yes that's a very good solution! It requiers no code so I'll take it :) I'll try to upvote you with my other account I use for normal StackExchange, thanks a lot!